# How to specify number type when initialize array directly

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I need to initialize an array using direct initializing (ActionScript 3). Like this:

```
private var aa: Array;

function init() {

    aa = [0x0050, 0x00ff, 0xff22];

}
```

I guess aa will contain array of numbers of any type that compiler wants. But I need them to be type of "int". How should I tell that for compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Array` class will not only contain any number type, it will contain **any combination** of types like

```
aa = ['apple', new MovieClip (), 123, 22.55]
```

Use the built-in `Vector` class which is a typed `Array` essentially. You can read more at the [official page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html).

```
var v:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int> ();
```

Answer (score 1):

Array cannot be typed. You can use Vector instead of Array. This will be looks like:

```
private var aa:Vector.<int>;

function init():void {
    aa = new <int>[0x0050, 0x00ff, 0xff22];
}
```